# Units in Euclidean domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

I'm studying basic Ring Theory. And in my textbook, the author states the definition of Euclidean domain:
An integral domain $R$ is called to be a *Euclidean domain* precisely when there is a function $f: R\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow\Bbb N_0$, called degree function of $R$, such that:
(i) If $a,b \in R\setminus\{0\}$ and there exists $c\in R$ such that $ac=b$ then $f(a)\le f(b)$.
(ii) $a,b\in R$ with $b\neq 0$, then there exist $q,r\in R$ such that 
$a=bq + r$ with $r=0$ or $r\neq 0$ and $f(r)\lt f(b)$.

I know the fact: all units in $R$ have smallest degree, and this question pops into my head:

> I want to prove that all units have degree $0$.

Unfortunately I have no idea for it. Can anyone has an answer for my question or give me a readable explanation about it? I really appreciate !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prove that units have degree $0$: if $f\colon R\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{N}_0$ is a degree function, also
$$
f_k\colon R\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{N}_0,
\qquad f_k(a)=f(a)+k
$$
is a degree function as well, for every integer $k\ge -f(1)$ (because $f(1)$ is the minimum value attained by $f$).

You can *normalize* your degree function, by defining
$$
\hat{f}(a)=f(a)-f(1)
$$
and now units will have degree $0$ with respect to $\hat{f}$.

Answer (score 0):

Proving all units having degree 0 somehow means for any function f, they have degree 0. But I can always define a new degree function by adding 1 to an existing one. Now no one has degree 0.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You are answering a 6 year old question, that already had an accepted answer, and your answer is a special case of the answer that was already given. You have added nothing new. What was the point? This is not useful (-1).